# In a model of ETCS with all colimits, is every set isomorphic to a coproduct of 1's?

Tags: category-theory, foundations, topos-theory

Supposing we have a model of the Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets ([nLab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS)) which has all colimits. Is every set isomorphic to a coproduct of terminal objects (indexed over some discrete category)?

Comment: Probably relevant is [this question on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27219/proof-that-objects-are-colimits-of-generators).

Answer (score 5):

As Lawvere proves in his original [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC300477/pdf/pnas00186-0196.pdf), any models of ETCS with small products and coproducts are equivalent. Thus such a category as you request is equivalent to the usual category of sets.

Comment: Do you know if the precise statement is that given a model $\mathcal S$ of ETCS, another model of $\mathcal S'$ ETCS  that is enriched in $\mathcal S$ and $\mathcal S$-complete is ($\mathcal S$-enriched) equivalent to $S$?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know.